# Get the selected item (item id) of SharePoint list (On Premise 2019) with SPFx and React

Tags: web-part, spfx, react

I am trying to customize the edit form of SharePoint list using web part SPFx.

I need to get "item id" of selected item and the send it with query string to new page (custom edit page).

have you any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to get the selected list item ID from List View only? or you want to fetch the item Id from URL of default edit page?

Answer (score 0):

**Use this:**

```
var ID = getParameterByName("ID", window.location.href);

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```